# Border-top works inside first-child, but not border-bottom

Tags: css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I trying to learn some of CSS, but I'm having a little trouble.

In my project I have one searchbar with "ui autocomplete", this works, but I'm trying to edit the style of the "returns box" and having some troubles.

Now my autocomplete result box doesn't show the border-bottom, and I'm trying to solve this. When I type border-bottom: 10px inside a Last-Child I don't have success, but when I type border-top: 10px inside a First-Child I have!

**CSS:**

```
.ui-corner-all{
    background-color: #FFF;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
}

ul.ui-autocomplete{
    border-top: 0px solid rgb(223, 223, 223) !important;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
}

ul.ui-autocomplete li:first-child{
    /* border-top: 10px solid rgb(223, 223, 223); */
}

ul.ui-autocomplete li:last-child{
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    border: 0px;
    height: 32px;
} 

.ui-state-focus, .ui-menu .ui-menu-item a:hover,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-hover,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-active {
    background: rgb(223, 223, 223);
    background-image: none !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
    zoom: 0%;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.0;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    min-height: 0;
    color: #000;
}
```

**Html:**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="search_bar">
  <input type="search" name="search" class="giant-input" autofocus list="hashtags" size="60" />
</form>
```

Am I doing something wrong? What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Without additional coding, it is difficult to identify the problem. EDIT: Have you tried :nth-child(2)..? maybe it isn't the last child, rather the second..? just a suggestion

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML and/or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Yes, I will post today in the midday. Thanks for your replies and sorry for slow reply :/

Comment: Question updated, now you can help me guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I found the solution!

I did proof by exhaustion in my code and I discover the root of the problem. It's just (I don't know why) a padding: 0px the problem.

**My original code:**

```
.ui-corner-all{
    background-color: #FFF;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
}
```

**My new code(working!):**

```
.ui-corner-all{
    background-color: #FFF;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0px;
    // padding: 0px; -- Here's the problem
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
}
```

Thanks for the friends who tried help! :)